# Pumping lemma for CFG

Tags: formal-languages, context-free-grammar

it is another my question. Can you give me hint to solve the following problem?

> Prove that $L=\left\{a^{n^2}:n\ge 0\right\}$ is not a context-free language?

Thanks!

Comment: Please check to be sure that I correctly interpreted what you wrote. Also, are you trying to prove that $L$ is context-free or that it is not? The pumping lemma is a tool for proving that a language is **not** context-free.

Comment: sorry, i wrote wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $L$ is not context-free, and you can use the [pumping lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages) to show this. Suppose that $L$ is regular, let $p$ be the pumping length, and let $w=a^{p^2}$. The pumping lemma says that we can decompose $w$ as $w=uvxyz$ in such a way that $|vxy|\le p$, $|vy|\ge 1$, and $uv^kxy^kz\in L$ for every $k\ge 0$. Obviously in this case each of the pieces $u,v,x,y$, and $z$ will just be a string of $a$’s. Let $m=|vy|\ge 1$.

- Show that $|uv^kxy^kz|=p^2-m+km=p^2+(k-1)m$ for each $k\ge 0$.
- Explain why it’s impossible that every term of the arithmetic progression $$\big\langle p^2+(k-1)m:k\ge 0\big\rangle$$ is a perfect square. (Extra hint: How far apart are $n^2$ and $(n+1)^2$?)

Comment: i see see, huge thanks!

Comment: @nuraureum: You’re very welcome.